# Angular animate Left is not working

Tags: css, angular, typescript, animation, components

im making a component for a Slider but the transition of the "left" property of css is not working, i don't know what i'm doing wrong.

This is my animation:

```
animations: [
    trigger('slide', [
      state('move1', style({
        left: '{{left}}'
      }),{params: {left: '0px'}}),
      state('move2',   style({
        left: '{{left}}'
      }),{params: {left: '0px'}} ),
      transition('move1 <=> move2', animate('350ms ease-in-out'))
    ])
  ]
```

I'm passing the value of "left" dinamicly but is not working the animation betweent the states.

The value of left works perfect and it changes correctly, but the animation is simply not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

You're essentially doing nothing with your animation, and maybe that's why that you're not seeing any changes even though the state is changing in the DOM.  For example in your code you have:

> params: {left: '0px'}}

for both of your states.

What you need to have is a different attribute value on the second state to see some distinguishing factor.  For example in your code you could have something that looks like this:

```
animations: [
  trigger('slide', [
  state('move1', style({
    left: '{{left}}'
  }),{params: {left: '0px'}}),
  state('move2',   style({
    left: '{{left}}'
  }),{params: {left: '500px'}} ),
  transition('move1 <=> move2', animate('350ms ease-in-out'))
])]
```

This way, in the second state, the element is moving 500px to the left.  I will provide another example is explicity state what I'm getting at.

```
animations: [
trigger(
  'myAnimation',
  [
    transition(
    ':enter', [
      style({transform: 'translateY(-100%)', opacity: 0}),
      animate('500ms', style({transform: 'translateY(0)', 'opacity': 1}))
    ]
  ),
  transition(
    ':leave', [
      style({transform: 'translateY(0)', 'opacity': 1}),
      animate('500ms', style({transform: 'translateY(-100%)', 'opacity': 0})),
    ]
  )]
)]
```

Notice the variation in the parameter values for translateY.  Hopefully, that clears some things up!  Good luck! :D